# Correct approach to code an AngularJS directive to generate a table from an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to create **a directive that generate a full table from an array**, offers specific onMouseOver behaviour, and when a cell is clicked, emphasizes all cells with same value (and other specific behaviours that are not important for this example).

```
// AngularJS controller
$scope.myArrayOfValues = [[0,1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9]];
// Page HTML
<my-table-directive values='myArrayOfValues'></my-table-directive>
```

I've thought of the following approaches, but I'm unsure they are among the best practices for such a problem.

NB. For the sake of brevity, the pieces of code below just generate the table from the array, but do not offer the additionnal behaviour described above.

**(1) Using directive 'template' property**

```
app.directive('myTableDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            values: '='
        },
        template: '<table class="ffrs-table">' +
                '<tr>' +
                  '<th ng-repeat="cell in data.labels">{{cell}}</td>' +
                '</tr>' +
                '<tr ng-repeat="row in data.values track by $index">' +
                  '<td class="centered" ng-repeat="cell in row track by $index">{{cell}}</td>' +
                '</tr>' +
              '</table>',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs)
        {
            //elem.children() does not return tr/th/td DOM elements
        }
    };
});
```

But this approach does not allow table DOM elements manipulation in the `link` function this they do not seem to exist inside this function.

**(2) jQuery table creation**

```
app.directive('myTableDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: false,
        scope: {
            values: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs)
        {
            scope.$watch( 'tableData', function(val)
            {
                if( val ) {
                    var row;
                    for( var t=0; t<val.values.length; t++ ) {
                        row = angular.element('<tr></tr>');
                        for( var f=0; f<val.values[t].length; f++ ) {
                            row.append( '<td>' + val.values[t][f] + '</td>');
                        }
                        elem.append( row );
                    }
                }
                elem.addClass('my-table-css-class');
            }
        }
    };
});
```

In this approach, there is still an issue, as the `addClass` call seems to apply to the element as it was **before** the tr/td element additions.

**(3) `ng-repeat` and use of directive on each tr/th/td element**
This is an approach I've not tested since I have more than 20 tables to display and the shorter the table code is in the HTML file, the better...

So the question is: what is the correct approach? Or maybe none of them are correct and such is problem should be solved in another way?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are on the right track with approach #1. Instead of trying to accomplish what you need within the link function I would suggest adding a controller to this directive with functions that are triggered by `ng-click` and `ng-mouseover`:

```
controller: ['$scope', function MyTableController($scope) {
  $scope.doSomething = function() {
    // your code here
  };

  $scope.highlightSameValues = function(cell) {
    // your code here
  };
}];
```

So, for example, if you want certain "things" to happen when you mouse over and click each cell alter your `td` to the following:

```
<td
  class="centered"
  ng-repeat="cell in row track by $index"
  ng-mouseover="doSomething()"
  ng-click="highlightSameValues(cell)">
  {{cell}}
</td>
```